# where i can learn WSO2 ESB expressions

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am doing some POC using WSO2 ESB and other stack. I have seen different expression for property files in some examples scenario. 
i.e. expression="get-property('registry','conf:/test.xml')"
expression="$ctx:customerID"

can anyone tell me where i can find all these expression syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions are about retrieving the value. These will be useful,
http://rajikak.blogspot.com/2010/04/xpath-functions-and-properties-avilable.html
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Mediators

The second points to official documentation of WSO2 ESB where each mediator is explained in detail.

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't understand the WSO2 ESB expressions. But the first link you have provided don't  work anymore. Any other links?

Answer (score 0):

Below link explain all the expression we need to access the message passing through the ESB.
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Properties+Reference